# Can't delete Azure/Office 365 organization

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to close an Microsoft 365 organization that I have made for testing purposes. I have followed this [Microsoft Docs guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/close-your-account?view=o365-worldwide).

So far I have deleted all the users, and canceled all the active subscriptions. A couple of days I was able to delete the subscriptions, when they ran out. So now I do not have any licenses associated with my organization.

I then proceeded to disable multi-factor authentication, but when I was about to delete the directory in the Azure Active Directory I am greeted with this:

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOJbu.jpg

When I click the *Delete all enterprise applications*, I am presented to this page:

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcX9Y.jpg

I am global administrator in the organization and I am allowed to manage the tenant. Does anyone know what I should do in order to delete the organization?

Comment: I've done this _once_. I had to contact Microsoft Support to remove the last of the Enterprise Applications. That would be my only suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try to contact MS Support.